# "Kомпания — производитель продуктов питания" — здесь следует поставить дефис или тире?

Tags: дефис-тире

«Нестле» — крупнейшая в мире компания — производитель продуктов питания и напитков, эксперт в области правильного питания и
здорового образа жизни

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Компания-производитель" пишется с дефисом (дефисное написание приложения). Но у Вас приложение "производитель" расширено, и в силу вступает следующее правило:

> [§ 154. В следующих случаях вместо дефиса должен употребляться знак тире.](http://www.orthographia.ru/orf.php?paragraph=pp154.php)
>   1. В сочетаниях с приложением, если одна из частей содержит пробел.
>   Примеры с неоднословными приложениями: творчество поэтов — современников Пушкина; статьи о Горьком — общественном деятеле, о Маршаке — переводчике Шекспира; печальная судьба дома — памятника архитектуры; обратиться к директору — художественному руководителю; среди стран — участников переговоров. Ср. поэты-современники, Горький-писатель, Маршак-переводчик, дом-памятник, директор-распорядитель.

Примеры можно найти в Нацкорпусе:

> Также совместно с **компанией ― производителем систем ЭКГ «ИТМ-Миокард»** на базе нетбуков ASUS были созданы мобильные кардиосканеры и изготовлены мобильные рабочие места для применения в стационарах. [Объявлены лауреаты премии в области инноваций «Время инноваций — 2012» // «Эксперт», 2013]
>
> Число **компаний-производителей инклинометрических сенсоров** исчисляется десятками, а общие тиражи изделий ― миллионами. [В. М. Ольшанский, Д. С. Павлов, С. В. Волков, Д. Э. Эльяшев. Электрические рыбы ― биологический прототип новой техники // «Вестник РАН», 2009]

В последнем примере дефис поставлен по ошибке, должно быть тире.

Проблема в том, что в Вашем предложении стоит два тире, каждое по своей причине, но создается ложное впечатление, что эти два тире поставлены для обособления слов "крупнейшая в мире компания". Минимальное изменение, которое я могу предложить в качестве решения этой проблемы, — добавление слова "это".

**«Нестле» — это крупнейшая в мире компания — производитель продуктов питания и напитков, эксперт в области правильного питания и здорового образа жизни.**

Comment: Этому предложению с двумя тире уже ничего не поможет, даже связка "это". Что касается правила о применении тире, то его использованию препятствует ОДНОРОДНЫЙ РЯД приложений (производитель, эксперт). Весь ряд к слову "компания" отнесете или как?

Comment: Эксперт относится к "Нестле", а к "компании"  — только производитель. Нет однородного ряда.

Comment: Это Вы так думаете, что нет, а  на самом деле это не очевидно, можно увидеть там однородные отношения. Поэтому правильно понять назначение двух тире весьма сложно. Они останавливают на себе внимание читателя и вызывают недоумение.

Comment: @Ксения, Ваш вариант звучит лучше, но я хотел показать, что можно обойтись минимальной правкой (я не согласен с тем, что "уже ничего не поможет").

Answer (score 2):

Вариант редактирования:

***Компания «Нестле» — крупнейший в мире производитель продуктов питания и напитков, эксперт в области правильного питания и здорового образа жизни.***

**Пояснение**

Существует сложное слово ***компания-производитель*** с дефисным написанием, но оно обычно используется без зависимых слов, например:

**Компания-производитель** Idaho Teсhnology  получила уже несколько сотен заказов... «Известия», 2001.10.23]

**Компания-производитель** может гарантировать стабильную работу своих дисплеевв жестких климатических условиях... «Наружная реклама России», 2003.10.20]